# Make env file as .gitignore in djangp project?

Tags: git, gitignore

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdOdh.png)    How to move my broenv (env folder) folder inside gitignore. I don't want to store my broenv folder to Github. How can I remove that from github? Plzzz help!

Is that okay to store env folder in github?.

I  don't  want  to  store  my  broenv(env)  folder  to  Github repository.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your `.gitignore` file:

```
broenv/
```

It is recommended to not publish `.env` files on GitHub